# URL Rewrite with encoded and "unencoded" special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, encoding, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to write redirects for a list of URLs and got some problems because they contain encoded as well as "unencoded" special characters.

Example:

```
http://example.com/lvl-+-1/écrire/gar%C3%A7ons/2/fr
```

As you can see, there is an `é` as well as encoded characters like `%C3%A7` (for ç) in the same URL. How can I write a redirect for this?

Currently I'm trying the following, I already escaped the `+`characters with `\`:

```
RewriteRule ^lvl-\+-1/écrire/gar%C3%A7ons/2/fr https://www.example.com/Boîtes [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

The new URLs contains special characters like `î`, therefore I set the `NE`tag.
Unfortunately this isn't working, because I guess the characters are either not encoded at all or twice.

Is there a way to catch such URLs with with "unencoded" and encoded characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `%` character use hex notation as `\xMN`.

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^lvl-\+-1/écrire/gar\xC3\xA7ons/2/fr/?$ /Boîtes [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I know added two redirects for each of these cases, so one with e.g. \xC3\xA7 and one with ç.